# Ada2012: possible error for Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled?

Tags: oop, ada

I'm facing now the following weird run-time error:

> raised PROGRAM_ERROR : s-finroo.adb:42 explicit raise

I'm trying to implement an [Observer design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer). Since my observers are limited and I want to avoid general access types, I'm storing the observers' address and notifying them using Ada.Adress_To_Access_Conversions.
My concrete observers are inheriting from Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled as I have to initialize and finalize them somehow as per my implementation.
Take a look at components.ads below, where Component_t is defined.

I leave you a minimal reproducibable example:

**eventpublisher.ads**

```
private with System;

package eventPublisher is

  type Observer_t is limited interface;
  procedure Event (this : in out Observer_t) is abstract;

  type EventPublisher_t is tagged limited private;
  procedure pSubscribeEvent (this : in out EventPublisher_t;
                             TrainId : Natural;
                             sub : Observer_t'Class);

  procedure pUnsubscribeEvent (this : in out EventPublisher_t;
                               TrainId : Natural;
                               sub : Observer_t'Class);

  procedure pNotifyEvent (this : in out EventPublisher_t);

  function fGetEventPublisher return not null access EventPublisher_t;

private

  type EventObserver_t is tagged
     record
       obs : System.Address := System.Null_Address;
     end record;

  type EventPublisher_t is tagged limited
     record
       eventManager : EventObserver_t;
     end record;

end eventPublisher;
```

**eventpublisher.adb**

```
with System.Address_To_Access_Conversions;
with Ada.Text_IO;

package body eventPublisher is

  function "=" (Left, Righ : System.Address) return Boolean renames System."=";

  eventPublisher : access EventPublisher_t := new EventPublisher_t;

  package Event_OPS is new System.Address_To_Access_Conversions (Observer_t'Class);

  function fGetEventPublisher return not null access EventPublisher_t is
  begin
    return eventPublisher;
  end fGetEventPublisher;

  -------------------
  -- pSubscribeEvent --
  -------------------

  procedure pSubscribeEvent
    (this : in out EventPublisher_t; TrainId : Natural;
     sub  :        Observer_t'Class)
  is
  begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Subscribing to Event");
    this.eventManager.obs := sub'Address;
  end pSubscribeEvent;

  procedure pUnsubscribeEvent (this : in out EventPublisher_t;
                               TrainId : Natural;
                               sub : Observer_t'Class) is
  begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Unsubscribing to Event");
    if this.eventManager.obs = sub'Address then
      this.eventManager.obs := System.Null_Address;
    else
      null;
    end if;

  end pUnsubscribeEvent;

  procedure pNotifyEvent (this : in out EventPublisher_t) is
  begin
    if this.eventManager.obs /= System.Null_Address then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Notifying to observer");
      Event_OPS.To_Pointer(this.eventManager.obs).Event;
    end if;
  end pNotifyEvent;
```

**components.ads**

```
with eventPublisher;
private with Ada.Finalization;

package components is

  type Root_t (Id : Natural) is abstract tagged limited null record;

  type Child_t (Id : Natural) is limited new Root_t with private;

  procedure pSubscribe (this : in out Child_t);
  procedure pUnsubscribe (this : in out Child_t);

private

  type Component_t (Id : Natural) is limited new
    Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled and --> if you comment out this, everything works
    eventPublisher.Observer_t with null record;

  overriding
  procedure Event (this : in out Component_t);

  type Child_t (Id : Natural) is limited new Root_t (Id => Id) with
     record
       component : Component_t(Id => Id);
     end record;

end components;
```

**components.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

package body components is
  -----------
  -- Event --
  -----------

  overriding procedure Event (this : in out Component_t) is
  begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Processing Event");
  end Event;
  ----------------
  -- pSubscribe --
  ----------------

  procedure pSubscribe (this : in out Child_t) is
  begin
    eventPublisher.fGetEventPublisher.pSubscribeEvent(TrainId => this.Id,
                                                    sub => this.component);
  end pSubscribe;

  procedure pUnsubscribe (this : in out Child_t) is
  begin
    eventPublisher.fGetEventPublisher.pUnsubscribeEvent(TrainId => this.Id,
                                                      sub => this.component);
  end pUnsubscribe;

end components;
```

And finally, **main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with components;
with eventPublisher;

procedure Main is

  c : components.Child_t(Id => 1);
  pub : constant access eventPublisher.EventPublisher_t := eventPublisher.fGetEventPublisher;

begin
  c.pSubscribe;
  pub.pNotifyEvent;
  c.pUnsubscribe;
end Main;
```

This is the backtrace:

```
#0  <__gnat_debug_raise_exception> (e=0x45ab60 <program_error>, message=...) at s-excdeb.adb:41
#1  0x0000000000407265 in ada.exceptions.complete_occurrence (x=x@entry=0x467300) at a-except.adb:1019
#2  0x0000000000407275 in ada.exceptions.complete_and_propagate_occurrence (x=x@entry=0x467300) at a-except.adb:1030
#3  0x00000000004076ac in ada.exceptions.raise_with_location_and_msg (e=0x45ab60 <program_error>, f=(system.address) 0x4437d8, l=42, c=c@entry=0, m=m@entry=(system.address) 0x441150) at a-except.adb:1241
#4  0x0000000000407629 in <__gnat_raise_program_error_msg> (file=<optimized out>, line=<optimized out>, msg=msg@entry=0x441150 <ada.exceptions.rmsg_22>) at a-except.adb:1197
#5  0x00000000004078e0 in <__gnat_rcheck_PE_Explicit_Raise> (file=<optimized out>, line=<optimized out>) at a-except.adb:1435
#6  0x0000000000416ba5 in system.finalization_root.adjust ()
#7  0x0000000000404fea in eventpublisher.pnotifyevent ()
#8  0x00000000004041be in main ()
```

Do you know what the heck is going on? Why the run-time is calling to Adjust for a Limited_Controlled type at trace #6?

Comment: I still don't know what is happening but, if I override an Adjust method to null, then the compiler complains about is not overriding. If I put "not overriding", the compiler complains about it is overriding... If I don't put anything to the adjust, the call to #6 is null so nothing fails...

Comment: Really looks like a compiler bug. Goes back to GCC 9.

Answer (score 2):

In [this article](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Advanced&CID=213) the late Robert Dewar (founder of AdaCore) says

> NEVER use Address_To_Access_Conversions with pointers to unconstrained array types.

I know you don't have unconstrained array types, but the type concerned is moderately complex.

I made minimal changes to your code, and it ran without problem.

```
   type Observer_Class_P is access all Observer_T'Class;
```

---

```
   procedure pSubscribeEvent (this : in out EventPublisher_t;
                              TrainId : Natural;
                              sub : Observer_t'Class);
```

---

```
   type EventObserver_t is tagged
      record
         obs : Observer_Class_P;
      end record;
```

---

```
   procedure pSubscribeEvent
     (this : in out EventPublisher_t; TrainId : Natural;
      sub  :        Observer_t'Class)
   is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Subscribing to Event");
      this.eventManager.obs := sub'Unrestricted_Access; -- sorry about this :-(
   end pSubscribeEvent;
```

---

```
   procedure pNotifyEvent (this : in out EventPublisher_t) is
   begin
      if this.eventManager.obs /= null then
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Notifying to observer");
         this.eventManager.Obs.Event;
      end if;
   end pNotifyEvent;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Simon! This is very similar to my previous implementation, I was not using Unrestricted_Access but Unchecked_Access and a lot of general access types to be able to do named access conversions. I just wanted to avoid the usage of those general access types according what I found about them in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/access

Answer (score 2):

Ok, one thing to consider is alternate methods for interfacing. In particular, have you considered generics?

```
GENERIC
   Type Subscriber is private;
   with procedure Event (this : in out Subscriber) is <>;
   with package Notification_List is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vector
         (Element => Subscriber, others => <>);
   Notification : in out Notification_List.Vector;
PROCEDURE Do_Notification;
```

and

```
PROCEDURE Do_Notification is
begin
   For C of Notification.Iterate loop
      Notification.Update_Element( C, Event'Access );
   end loop;
end Do_Notification;
```

And now, with the above construction, you can use non-tagged types as your Subscriber! -- Though for your particular case, you'll need to instantiate `Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vector` with `Observer_T'Class`.

Comment: Thank you! How will this work if the Subscriber generic formal type is declared as non-limited and indefinite and you will declare the package instance with the observer interface? I'll try it.

Comment: If you need indefinite, then make the declaration of the formal-parameter of the generic `Subscriber(<>)`. And the generic *IS* the observer, you don't have to do anything else except ensure that the `Event` parameter is supplied.